# How do I use two Git accounts on the same computer?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'am working with one project and we use Git with https://bitbucket.org but now I will also start working in another project that has a different bitbucket account. How can I work with this two projects from the same computer and use different git config file and git remote url?

E.g in my current project, I have the following setup

```
user.name=Martin Andersson
user.email=test@test.com
remote.origin.url=https://martin-andersson@bitbucket.org/123456/123456.git
```

but my new project will have the following setup

```
user.name=name-company
user.email=company@company.com
remote.origin.url=https://name-company@bitbucket.org/abcd/abcd.git
```

How can I easily switch between these accounts in Git terminal and keep all the settings, commits etc

Comment: Think there is probably a better way than this but my first thought would be to setup multiple user accounts on your dev box then you could use "run-as" when you wanted to use the different config settings

Answer (score 3):

Well it's simple, don't use the --global option when using git config. This will set the configuration for the specific repo you are currently in.

For more details, read the documentation:

http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration

Answer (score 2):

You can set different configuration for different git repos. More details here: https://orrsella.com/2013/08/10/git-using-different-user-emails-for-different-repositories/